# what does the error "HookUndefined Step" mean when using cucumber JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I have a cucumberJS project that is currently using the webdriverIO v5 framework, which was recently integrated. I was wondering if you can help me troubleshoot this error.

I just upgraded my framework from webdriverIO v4 to v5, and in v4 this issue was not happening but in v5 after I was able to finally get all of my tests to run I started to encounter this error.

Here is a screenshot of the error that I am receiving.

[image: HookUndefined Step Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the reporter of WebdriverIO. The `before` and `after` hook don't have a step description and the reporter see's this as an undefined issue.

I filled an issue for that which can be found here

https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4175

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to the fix.

Comment: It's fixed, see https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v5112-2019-07-11